# NSUserDefaults Initializer

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, init

Im learning about NSUserDefaults and I have a class that instantiates a person with a first and last name.

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!

    init(first:String, last:String) {
        firstName = first
        lastName = last
    }

    override init() {

    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.firstName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as? String
        self.lastName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("lastName") as? String
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.firstName, forKey: "firstName")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.lastName, forKey: "lastName")
    }
}
```

I am wondering why I have to override my first initializer that has initializes first and last names with an empty initializer?

Also, what exactly is a "required convenience" initializer?

Thank you

Comment: Please read the [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

Comment: http://www.codingexplorer.com/designated-initializers-convenience-initializers-swift/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `NSObject`'s initializer in your custom initializer:

```
init(first:String, last:String) {
    firstName = first
    lastName = last

    super.init()
}
```